# c#: how to enforce classes Presentation Layer from calling Dal Layer?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, aop, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm looking for a Roslyn check / Resharper Annotation / Postsharp or any extension of Visual Studio where I can **force** a class from the UI to **not call** the Dal.

Comment: How are you categorising your classes as UI or DAL? Maybe review your architecture/design to restrict access to calling the DAL. Your question needs more details.

Comment: @PiersMyers: thanks for the fast answer! I'm not sure I've completely understood the question. The architecture is already layered, but any developer can add a new Reference to the DAL and call it from the UI. Actually, the problem is even worse, I already have a reference to the DAL in my UI.. is there any "contract" to enforce the developer to avoid calling DAL classes from UI classes?

Comment: I don't think there is, time to create some coding standards and code reviews to help enforce them.